# Jquery $.get() and $.ajax() don't get same result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use the two different AJAX way to send/receive data from php file but can't get the same result

data.php

```
<?php
echo "hello";
?>
```

$.get()

```
if($(this).val() != '')
{
  $.get(
  'data.php',
  { what: $(this).val() },
  function(data)
  {
    $('#result').html(data);
    alert(data);
  });
}
```

$.ajax()

```
$('#choice').change(function()
{
  if($(this).val() != '')
  {
    $.ajax({type: GET, url: "data.php", complete: function(){alert("complete");}, success: function(data){alert(data);}, error: function(){alert("error");}});
});
}
```

.get() will return "hello" while .ajax() return nothing even no error.

Comment: Could be due to a syntax error, unless the above isn't a copy/paste.   It should be `type: "GET"`

Comment: Where is the corresponding `data` property in `$.ajax`?

Comment: Check your Javascript console for errors.

Comment: Is `GET` a typo or you actually have a variable with that name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap `GET` inside quotes:

```
type: "GET"
```